# Why does safari say my website is insecure when a user is entering a password - Django

Tags: django, security, ssl, safari

And to add to the question, how do I make it secure.

So the situation is, is that I have a website that I have deployed and I have a sign up form. Whenever I click on sign up and start typing in my information and i get to writing my password, safari warns me that my website is insecure. Why is this? And how do I fix it?

EDIT: By the way, I am including {% csrf_token %} in all my POST forms

Comment: This site uses HTTP, and not https, most of browsers warn users for unencrypted sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you are not using HTTPS.

When you serve your website over HTTP, the data is sent in plain text over the internet.

This means that, when the user submits the password to your website, it could be read in transit. This is not secure.

You are now able to get free certificates for your website using https://letsencrypt.org/.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and the link. This appears to be a bigger rabbit hole than I thought, do you know of any resources where I can learn about all this in detail other than the django documentation. Because I have a very small understanding about SSL, HTTPS and everything like that

Comment: It's a big subject, but don't let that put you off... there's a lot of support out there. This might be a good place to start: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your certificate is self-signed? Maybe you then need to specify in the settings to allow certificates from localhost.